# How to implement server sent events in Jersey 1?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I have a web service running on tomcat. It uses Jersey. I need to implement some way to push notifications to client from server asynchronously (like SSE). I am aware that servlet 3.0 has this, and Jersey 2 implements this, but, my (huge) tomcat webapp project is implemented using Jersey 1.13, and uses Jersey 1 things like jersey-guice, which, if I move to Jersey 2, will have to be changed.

Is there any way I can do this?